# Error: To get user input for a dynamically allocated 2D array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, scanf, calloc

I'm trying to write a basic fixed size array of dynamically allocated array(for when we only know one dimension of a 2D array) and getting the user input for the matrix.

I've learnt that after you declared the dynamically allocated 2D matrix, you can accessed it like a fixed length 2D array. 
So I tried to use scanf to get user input for the dynamically allocated 2D array just like how I did for the fixed length 2D array.

For fixed length 2D array, I did this and it works:

```
long bar[3][3];

printf("input 9 elements: ");

for (r = 0; r < 3; r += 1) {

    for (c = 0; c < 3; c += 1) {

        scanf("%ld", &bar[r][c]);

    }

}
```

But when I did this for fixed size array of dynamically allocated array:

```
long *buckets[3], no_of_cols, no_of_rows, c;

printf("number of elements in each cols: ");
scanf("%ld", &no_of_cols);
for (no_of_rows = 0; no_of_rows < 3; no_of_rows += 1) {
buckets[no_of_rows] = calloc( no_of_cols, sizeof(long));
}

long m = no_of_cols * 3;
printf("input %ld elements: ", m);
for (no_of_rows = 0; no_of_rows < 3; no_of_rows += 1) {
    for(c = 0; c < no_of_cols; c += 1) {
    scanf("%ld" &buckets[no_of_rows][c]);
    }
}
```

I expect the program to write the user input into the array buckets. But when I run the program, it came out this error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression
  ('char *' and 'long')
            scanf("%ld" &buckets[no_of_rows][c]);
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong for the dynamically allocated 2D array causing this error. Please help me.

Comment: `scanf("%ld" &buckets[no_of_rows][c]);` should be `scanf("%ld", &buckets[no_of_rows][c]);` (Look carefully)

Comment: OH.... thank you so much! I was trying to debug this for like 2hours....

Comment: You're welcome. Happens to all of us :-) BTW, you might wanna delete this question as it is just a typo and is unlikely to help future readers

Comment: Aside: When allocating, consider allocating to the size of the de-referenced pointer, not the type.  Easier to code right, review and maintain. `buckets[no_of_rows] = calloc( no_of_cols, sizeof(long));` --> `buckets[no_of_rows] = calloc( no_of_cols, sizeof buckets[no_of_rows][0]);`